# rails generate controller stopped working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I've looked at both of ["rails generate controller" is not creating a controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134881/why-rails-generate-controller-is-not-working) and [rails 3 generate controller not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13369111/rails-3-generate-controller-not-working) and neither had an answer.

I've gone on to the rubyonrails freenode channel, and no answers there either.

I'm going through Michael Hartl's tutorial ( http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters ), and I've gotten to chapter 8.  Everything the night before was working perfectly, then the next morning, running "rails generate controller Sessions --no-test-framework" doesn't output anything and it doesn't create any files.  I've tried -p (pretend) and --trace to get any output, nothing.  Running the same command in a different app folder, it works perfectly fine.  I've tried "script/rails" but still the same.

However, "rails generate integration_test authentication_pages" works perfectly.

Does anyone know the cause of this and how to fix it?

Here's a link to the gist of my gems:  git@gist.github.com:3e2e6beacbef836a07cb.git | https://gist.github.com/3e2e6beacbef836a07cb

Comment: Yes I do, but I figured it out. Can't post the answer for a bit though.

Comment: OK, I figured it out.

I'm using RubyMine and someone on the rubyonrails channel mentioned that something might be overriding the controller generator, I had a second look. It seems that I created a controller generator from within RubyMine (unintentionally) and that was what was overriding the original controller generator. Being empty, it ran with exit code 0 and generated nothing. Deleting it solved the problem

Comment: you can answer your own question. Look at the bottom page.

Comment: I think you should change to use Sublime Text 2 as author mention. It's good and i think many rails developers use it.

Comment: I've just downloaded the demo version, I'll take a look at it and consider it. Thanks

Comment: it's not demo. It's complete software, but you will be asked for purchase some times when developing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured it out. I'm using RubyMine and someone on the rubyonrails channel mentioned that something might be overriding the controller generator, I had a second look. It seems that I created a controller generator from within RubyMine (unintentionally) and that was what was overriding the original controller generator. Being empty, it ran with exit code 0 and generated nothing. Deleting it solved the problem –

Answer (score -1):

@SteveMustafa

Thank you for posting that.  I had also generated a controller and was having the same issue.

I just deleted the file and it started working again.

Thanks!